# Sql server messed up degree symbol

Tags: sql-server, symbols

Some of the degree sysmbols in my sql server database are displaying like this: 173┬░F.

When I do a search for that - `SELECT * FROM PRoduct WHERE description LIKE '%┬░%'`, it does not bring them up.

How can I find (and replace) such characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should declare column as nvarchar and then start your strings like N' not '